# Manipulate, checkboxes from the list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to make a simple interface for making SQL SELECT query for smaller number of columns from a database with lot of columns in Mathematica.
I've got my List of column names, for example:

```
dbColumnNames={"name1","name2","name3",...."nameN"}
```

What I would like to do is to have a checkbox for each element of this list named the same as elements of the list, and when checked that I get list with column names checked.
For example, I click on "name1", "name50", "name74", the list should look like:

```
selectedNames={"name1","name50","name74"}
```

If I had that list, it's easy to make an SQL query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the help for [`CheckboxBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CheckboxBar.html) and [`TogglerBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TogglerBar.html).

Here is a working example:

```
dbColumnNames = {"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "nameN"};
TogglerBar[Dynamic[selected], dbColumnNames]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click the ones you want to select, then evaluate:

```
selected
```

To see the current value of that symbol.  The symbol name `selected` is arbitrary.

---

If you have long names, you may prefer:

```
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[selected], dbColumnNames, Appearance -> "Vertical"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have *a lot* of column names, you may prefer:

```
TextCell[
 TogglerBar[Dynamic[selected], dbColumnNames, Appearance -> "Row"],
 LineIndent -> 0
]
```

Comment: I used TextCell[CheckboxBar[Dynamic[selected], dbColumnNames], 
 LineIndent -> 0], not very pretty but it does the job. Thank you Mr.Wizard.

Comment: @enedene you are welcome.  Thanks for the Accept.  You say "not very pretty" -- are you referring to the code, or the output?  Perhaps we can improve this.

Comment: your code is fine, the output is a bit cumbersome since I have 330 columns. But I got what I wanted, I can dynamically and fast change SQL queries. For any aesthetics improvements I'll need to group these columns in some way so I don't loose functionality. That's not a priority right now.

Comment: @enedene, okay, post again if you need any help with that.

Comment: Actually I am doing a large scale test of szabolcs' figure post tool. Could as well make myself useful that way.